# How can I O.K. mongodb in php

Tags: php, mongodb

I want use mongodb Instead mysql in php.
I downloaded mongo driver php from https://s3.amazonaws.com/drivers.mongodb.org/php/index.html and copied to /opt/lampp/include/php/ext and append extension = php_mongo.dll to php.ini, then ran php code for test:

```html
<?php
// connect to mongodb


$m = new MongoClient();

echo "Connection to database successfully";
// select a database
$db = $m->salam;

echo "Database mydb selected";
?>
```

But when I use mongodb, an error occurs.: $m = new MongoClient();

Why is this happening?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: It's happening because something went wrong. With no further information, that's about all the help you can get.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have a unix-like system. Those drivers are for Windows (.dll for Windows - .so for unix) and they are outdated.

There are two different drivers for MongoDB: low level and high level drivers.
In order to use the MongoClient class, you need both.

Low level drivers:
https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-php-driver/

High level drivers:
https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-php-library/

Or you use your favorite repository.
Low level drivers will do the same job. They give you access to the MongoDB class. https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mongodb.php

Otherwise it would be great if you could provide a copy of your server's phpinfo.